# Can't install m2e plugin into IBM RTC Eclipse 6.0.6.1

Tags: eclipse, maven-plugin, m2eclipse, rational-team-concert

I want to integrate maven plugin into Eclipse RTC client (Team Concert, version 6.0.6.1).

[image]

How to fix it? Thks

I've tried to use other versions of that plugin:
https://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/
But the result is the same..

Comment: It is looking for the `org.eclipse.wst.sse.core` plug-in which is part of Eclipse Web Tools. You will have to tell the install about a software site containing a suitable version of the Web Tools.

Comment: What greg-449 says. Adding in the preferences _Install/Update > Available Software Sites_ the update site [`https://download.eclipse.org/releases/latest`](https://download.eclipse.org/releases/latest) should fix this issue.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add [one of the software repository matching your Eclipse version](https://download.eclipse.org/releases/)  (or, as commented, the [latest one](https://download.eclipse.org/releases/latest/))

[image: repository]

From there, re-try the M2E setup which, in turn, should find `org.eclipse.wst.sse.core`.